# Turn off validation of ssl certificate resttemplate spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a problem, when i need to turn off validation of ssl
certificate resttemplate in my spring api. I found this solution.

```
 @Bean
 public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyStoreException, 
 NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, 
String authType) -> true;
    SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
            .build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
            .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

But  in method setHttpClient i can`t inject my httpClient, cause required type of method setHttpClient is HttpClient.Everywhere i find only this way to disabling validation of ssl certificate. How i can resolve this problem?

Comment: You can use Spring Profiles - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: I`m just learning spring, can u explain what u mean and how i can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a "devRestTemplate" bean like this which would have your non-validation based `RestTemplate`:

```
@Bean(name = "restTemplate")
@Profile("dev")
public RestTemplate devRestTemplate() {
    ...
}
```

And your primary production `RestTemplate` bean...

```
@Bean(name = "restTemplate")
@Primary
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    ...
}
```

Then when you're running your app on your machine, you just need to specify the active profile to be "dev" and your non-validation bean would be used.

Please see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles for more information on using Spring Profiles.

Comment: How that fix setHttpClient can't receive CloseableHttpClient? Spring 3.1 can't handle apache http 4.x that's the issue.